# can array of pointers point to variable sized strings?

Tags: c

I like to know is this code wrong. reasons pleasec

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <malloc.h>

void func(char **c)
{
  strcpy(c[0],"he");
  strcpy(c[1],"h");
//  memcpy(*c[2],"hell",sizeof("hell"));
//  c[0]="hello";
  //c[1]="hi";
}

int main()
{
  char *arr[2];
  arr[0]=malloc(sizeof(char[3]));
  arr[1]=malloc(sizeof(char[2]));

  func(arr);
  printf("%s\n",arr[0]);
  printf("%s\n", arr[1]);

  return 0;
}
```

this line seems to allocate 3 * sizeof(char)

```
  arr[0]=malloc(sizeof(char[3]));
```

this line seems to allocate 2 * sizeof(char)

```
  arr[1]=malloc(sizeof(char[2]));
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong. On the other hand you need to know sizes of the allocated arrays that to apply the function strcpy correctly without memory overflow.

Comment: _"this line seems to allocate 3 * sizeof(char): `arr[0]=malloc(sizeof(char[3]));`"_: not only it seeems to allocate 3*sizeof(char) is actually does. `sizeof(x[y]])` is by definiton 
`y*sizeof(x)`

Comment: By definition, `sizeof(char) == 1`; `sizeof(char[3])` could be shortened to `3`.

Answer (score 1):

> can array of pointers point to variable sized strings?

Yes.

---

> is this code wrong.

`func()` is *brittle* in that it may exhibit *undefined behavior* depending on value of input.

- No information about how many `c[]` may be indexed.
- No information about how many bytes are available for `strcpy(c[i], ....)` to copy.

`func()` is *OK* in `main()` as it passes in a value that happens to not exceed the function limitations in OP's case.

`func()` is a *wrong* design in that is lacks parameters to guide its limitations and lacks *null pointer* error detection.